# Replacing the string

Tags: python, string, text

I want to do this task using python.
I have one .txt file which contains data like below.
sample:

```
Mumbai_xy.1 
id
1
Kolkata_xy.2
id
2
Mumbai_ab.1
id
3
Kolkata_ab.2
id
4
```

I want to open the file and replace the *_xy* with *_ab*. Also save as .txt file. Mumbai and kolkata are for sample.there is a long list.
Output .txt file will contains like..

```
Mumbai_ab.1
id
1
Kolkata_ab.2
id
2
```

Please help me here

Comment: have you formatted the file data correctly above?

Comment: You say you want to do this using Python, but it seems like you're asking us to do it using Python instead. What have you tried so far? What didn't work, what gave you trouble? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please put a sample in a code block, don't just list it out. Are those items on new lines of the file, or are just they sequential on one line? We need the exact data to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```py
old = open("old_file.txt").read() #Reading old .txt file
new_text = old.replace("_xy", "_ab") #Replacing texts

# Opening new txt file and saving it.
with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as new:
    file.write(new_text) #Writing new text in another .txt file
    file.close()
```

This should help you

Comment: Thank you . id also required to change . and also delete the _xy text.

Comment: No, as in example given in question. Id is not changed....

Comment: for Mumbai_ab.1 has id 3 in the sample. but in output it is 1. and Mumbai_xy.1 is deleted